# NHibernate - Why my DateTime property is always DateTime.MinValue

Tags: nhibernate

I have a [DataContract] called ReportRequest with a 
NOT NULL column 'SubmittedAt'. So my DataContract looks something like:

```
[DataContract]
public class ReportRequest
{
    Int32 templateId;
    DateTime submittedAt = DateTime.Now;

    [DataMember]
    public virtual Int32? Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }

    public virtual DateTime SubmittedAt
    {
        get {
              return submittedAt; 
        }
        set
        {
            submittedAt = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

Because, I have taken a private variable submittedAt and is initialised with DateTime.Now,

shouldn't the SubmittedAt property have the same value??

But when i am calling NHibernate

```
session.Save(objReportRequest);
```

I am getting the error:

*SqlDateTime overflow. Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.*

Any thoughts why I am getting this error?

As a workaround for now I have changed getter for SubmittedAt property as:

```
        get {
            if (submittedAt == DateTime.MinValue)
                return DateTime.Now;
            else
                return submittedAt; 
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because [DateTime.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.minvalue.aspx) doesn't have the same meaning as the minimum value you could store in a SQL Server datetime column. In SQL server datetime column the minimum date you could store is the one you get in your exception stack. It is [SqlDateTime.MinValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqltypes.sqldatetime.minvalue.aspx)

Comment: Thanks to all for your reply. I understand that SQL Server Min. Date Value is different from CLR DateTime.MinValue. But what I am confused about is what does following statement means to NHibernate: 
DateTime submittedAt = DateTime.Now; 

or it just ignores my setting of DateTime.Now ?

Comment: IMHO this is because the way you call your web service. Even that you set `submittedAt = DateTime.Now` if the caller of the web service doesn't explicitly set a date the xml serializer will explicitly call the setter and put `DateTime.MinValue`.

Answer (score 3):

SQL Server minimum DateTime value is bigger than DateTime.Min value. So you cannot save minimum value to database.

Comment: Even I don't want to, that's why I am initialising the property with DateTime.Now

Answer (score 1):

As Marek Tihkan already said: SqlServer can not store the `DateTime.MinValue`, it is outside of the value range of SqlServer's DateTime data type.

The best advise is to use nullable types anyway:

```
[DataContract]
public class ReportRequest
{
    DateTime? submittedAt = null;

    public virtual DateTime? SubmittedAt
    {
        get {
              return submittedAt; 
        }
        set
        {
            submittedAt = value; 
        }
    }
}
```

By `SubmittedAt.HasValue` you know if it is actually set to something reasonable. You shouldn't depend on some "magic values" to decide if a value is initialized or not.